# Can't work out how to run a macro within another macro

Tags: excel, vba, random

I'm very new to visual basic and have copied the following macro to run a random number generator.
This works fine. But I now want to copy and paste the number generated from the cell to another cell as paste values.  Then I want to generate the next number and copy and paste this new number. Basically I am trying to draw a 1st, 2nd and 3rd number and be able to show them as such after being randomly generated so that they do not change when the next number is generated.
I can't work out how to put a macro that copies and pastes the number each time after running the random number generator.

This is the code I copied for the random number generator

```
Sub BINGO()

Dim linenumber As Integer, numpick As Integer
Dim bingonum As String

linenumber = Range("E1").Value
numpick = Range("B" & linenumber).Value
Range("B" & linenumber).ClearContents

If numpick > 90 Then
bingonum = "W " & numpick
ElseIf numpick > 80 Then
bingonum = "A " & numpick
ElseIf numpick > 70 Then
bingonum = "R " & numpick
ElseIf numpick > 60 Then
bingonum = "D " & numpick
ElseIf numpick > 50 Then
bingonum = "* " & numpick
ElseIf numpick > 40 Then
bingonum = "3 " & numpick
ElseIf numpick > 30 Then
bingonum = "5 " & numpick
ElseIf numpick > 20 Then
bingonum = "8 " & numpick
ElseIf numpick > 10 Then
bingonum = "1 " & numpick
Else
bingonum = "HCC  " & numpick
End If

Range("G5").Value = bingonum


End Sub
```

Can anyone help.  I tried recording 3 macros to do the copy and paste and then added call macroname and did this 3 times.  This did it once but then doesn't loop and repeat.

thanks

Comment: Maybe store these numbers in an array like `Dim arr(1 to 3)` and run a `For i = 1 to 3` loop? But you'd need to also figure out how to get a random number three times from a single cell `E1`. I'd do it through VBA itself tbh. Do you have sample data to work with?

Comment: @JvdV, i'm using a simple list of 1 to 100 in col A and this is repeated in col B.  Then use rand function to generate random number in col C for all 100 rows. Col D then ranks the random number so it can get picked.  It then deletes it so it can't be picked twice. As the numbers are drawn they are formulated in a simple grid as per the above code.  The cell G5 is where the number drawn is shown each time.

Comment: @jvdV....It is basically a bingo calling grid that I am trying to adapt to pick 3 numbers in 1st, 2nd and 3rd order for a monthly draw.  So I then want to show the result of G5 in a simple list of 1st, 2nd and 3rd somewhere else on the spreadsheet but absolute so that after the first number is drawn its copied to say V1 but wont change when the second number is drawn and placed in V2 etc.